# Can I disable GCC's noreturn attribute for assert()

Tags: c++, gcc, assert, noreturn

Glibc uses GCC's `noreturn` attribute in `assert.h`:

```
extern void __assert_fail (...)
 ... __attribute__ ((__noreturn__));
```

**This causes GCC to optimize away all local variables and `this` pointer before breaking into debugger.** The optimization happens even at `-Og` level, and at `-O0` level so many other useful optimizations are omitted that testing becomes painfully slow.

Ideally I would like to just remove the `__noreturn__` attribute from there. I don't care if my `assert()` works a tiny bit faster, I want to see where and why it fired.

Is there a GCC command line flag or any other mechanism that I can use to disable the `__noreturn__` optimization, without disabling other optimizations?

---

**Runnable example code:**

```
#include <cassert>
int test(int x)
{
    assert(x != 1);
    return x + 10;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return test(argc);
}
```

This example asserts when it is run without arguments. When compiled with GCC 7.4 with `g++ -Og -g -ggdb -otest test.cc`, and running inside gdb, you can see the backtrace is useless:

```
#4  0x0000555555554676 in test (x=<optimized out>) at test.cc:4
#5  0x000055555555467f in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at test.cc:9
```

Comment: Are you sure it's assert and not -Og? Have you already created your own assert function and put that in place?

Comment: @JVApen Manually editing `/usr/include/assert.h` to comment out the attributes seems to stop it optimizing the locals away. But that seems rather brutal solution, and would mess up system upgrades.

Comment: You might still "overwrite" `assert` MACRO my your own.

Comment: @Jarod42: Which is a bit of work, since you want to only change the `__assert_fail` path. Still, some non-portable macro abuse might fix that. I imagine you'd add an extra argument/parameter  (!) e.g. `int()` to `__assert_fail`, and then add your own overloads which still calls the original.

Comment: Disabling the attribute might tickle the optimizer into retaining enough of `x` to see it in GDB in this case, but it’s not a fundamental change: after all, `x` *is* used in that function regardless.

Comment: @DavisHerring I admit I may not understand the entirety of the situation, but to me it seems that GCC notices that because __assert_fail() will never return, it has no need to retain `x` on the stack during the function call. Which is a quite fundamental change, as GCC is able to discard *all* local variables as soon as the assert fires, no matter if they would be used in other code paths or not.

Comment: @jpa: The Linux x64 ABI (for example; aka Itanium) passes them in registers anyway.  Maybe the `noreturn` avoids the need to spill them across the call, but it still probably has low reliability.

Answer (score 0):

Jarod42's comment about overwriting `assert` with custom macro gave an idea:

```
g++ -D__noreturn__=    ...usual options follow...
```

This works by just changing the attribute definition into empty brackets.
It is not pretty, but it at least works.

It would be nice if there was a somewhat specific optimization flag about discarding local variables before noreturn call, or something similar, but I haven't been able to find one. So this is best I have so far.